# Permissions needed to list databases

Tags: sql-server, permissions

A remote application is able to list database names if we give 'sa' rights to the application group. If we remove 'sa' rights, just with `public` server role they can't see databases, even the application group granted *data reader* and *data  writer*.

Answer (score 1):

By default the public server role can see all the databases.  You can change this by revoking VIEW ANY DATABASE to public.  You can restore it with:

```
use master 
grant view any database to public
```